# how to extract data from form-data in rust?

Tags: rust, form-data

I'm wondering how to I get data from form-data. I started to learn about rust and I'm doing CRUD functions:

```
----------------------------605243336009903535936235
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

123
----------------------------605243336009903535936235
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

TestName
----------------------------605243336009903535936235
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"

TestBody
----------------------------605243336009903535936235--
```

I pretty much wanna get id, name and body out from form-data and I don't know how to do it manually or if there is crate or something that can help me. Do I have to use string slices?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For such thing I would use a crate: in this case e.g. `multipart`.
https://docs.rs/multipart/0.18.0/multipart/server/struct.Multipart.html

```rust
use multipart::server::Multipart;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let body = "----------------------------605243336009903535936235\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"id\"\r
\r
123\r
----------------------------605243336009903535936235\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r
\r
TestName\r
----------------------------605243336009903535936235\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"body\"\r
\r
TestBody\r
----------------------------605243336009903535936235--";

    let mut mp = Multipart::with_body(
        body.as_bytes(),
        "--------------------------605243336009903535936235",
    );

    while let Some(mut field) = mp.read_entry().unwrap() {
        let data = field.data.fill_buf().unwrap();
        let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(data);
        println!("headers: {:?}, data: {}", field.headers, s);
    }
}

// out:
//
// headers: FieldHeaders { name: "id", filename: None, content_type: None }, data: 123
// headers: FieldHeaders { name: "name", filename: None, content_type: None }, data: TestName
// headers: FieldHeaders { name: "body", filename: None, content_type: None }, data: TestBody
```